# How to Locate and Disable Privacy Filter Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, internet

I am recently facing an issue where I'm suddenly loss my internet connectin. The pattern that i found is this thing happen after I open facebook website with Edge Chromium. I tried to disable firewall from Avast Premium but still no internet connection until i restart my laptop. Then I found that whenever I restart my PC there is a program called **Privacy Filter** that prevents me to restart. I am still not able to locate and disable this program and not sure whether this programm is provided by antivirus or windows.

Operating System: Windows 10 x64

Antivirus: Avast Premium

[image]

Comment: IIRC that’s just the window title, not necessarily the program name. Note that the window could be hidden.

Comment: If you want my honest guess, it’s your AV, almost guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem after I uninstall and reinstall Avast premium softwares. Confirmed by this forum [here](https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=301703.msg1652792#msg1652792) as well.